# How to jump from one folder to another folder in python after reading all the files in one folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, path

I'm writing the code to check the size of the files in many folders and directorys consecutively.

For example: I have a multiple directories and multiple files in each directory and also multiple files in each folder.

My code must read all the files in `D:/coding/dir1/folder1` like `sample1.txt, sample2.txt, sampl3.txt`.

after reading the files it should goto `D:/coding/dir1/folder2` and check `sample4.txt, sample5.txt, sample6.txt` etc. when reads all folders in a directory, It should jump to another directory (like `D:/coding/dir2/folder1`).

Let me know how can I achieve this.

```
D:/coding
- dir1
-- folder1
--- sample1.txt
--- sample2.txt
--- sample3.txt
-- folder2
--- sample4.txt
--- sample5.txt
--- sample6.txt
- dir2
-- folder1
--- sample7.txt
...
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a recursive function that returns all files and then read them in:

```
import os

def read_folder(folder):
    files = []
    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        f = os.path.join(folder, f)
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            files = [*files, *read_folder(f)]
        else:
            files.append(f)
    return files
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have the following folder structure

```
D:\coding
├───folder1
│       sample1.txt
│       sample2.txt
│
└───folder2
        sample1.txt
        sample2.txt
```

Use `pathlib` to find the files an use `stat` function to get the file size.

```py
from pathlib import Path

files = Path("D:/coding").rglob('*')
for f in files:
    if f.is_file():
        print(f'{str(f)} file size is : {f.stat().st_size}')
```

**output**

```
D:\coding\folder1\sample1.txt file size is : 728
D:\coding\folder1\sample2.txt file size is : 2378
D:\coding\folder2\sample1.txt file size is : 247
D:\coding\folder2\sample2.txt file size is : 1486
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

```
import os
import re
import glob path1 = r'D:\rmchal0\xml'
os.chdir(path1)
print(os.getcwd())
listdir = os.listdir(path1)
print(listdir)
def txt_check(path):
os.chdir(path)
listdir = os.listdir(path)
for files in listdir:
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
    # txt_file= files.endswith('.txt')
        file_size = os.path.getsize(files)
        if file_size > 0:
            print("this file has data: ", files, "with file size:", file_size, "in", os.getcwd())
print(listdir)
def file_size_check(path):
os.chdir(path)
print(os.getcwd())
listdir = os.listdir(path)
print(listdir)
for files in listdir:
    if (files.find('.') == -1):
        path2= os.path.join(path,files)
        if files.lower()== 'nok':
            print(files)
            txt_check(path2)
        else:
            #path2 = os.path.join(path,files)
            file_size_check(path2)
file_size_check(path1)
```